# How do I set up an Ubuntu virtual machine inside Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, virtualization

I would like to make a virtualization of Ubuntu inside Ubuntu, just to run unix benchmark om both Ubuntu one with full computer and another with less options.

Answer (score 4):

You can run an Ubuntu virtual machine inside an Ubuntu host.

You can use these:

[Oracle Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

which is available in `software center` and

[Vmware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/%E2%80%8E)

which you should download the bundle and install it yourself.

Note: VirtualBox is free, while VMWare Workstation is paid.

if any other question please ask..

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2020/08/07** to add alternatives to *VirtualBox* or *VmWare*

An alternative solution is *GNOME Boxes*. It is a system virtualization application (based on the QEMU machine emulator) that is a core part of the GNOME desktop environment. It is a virtualization app that allows you to quickly create a virtual system without fiddling with too many options and choices. It is not a highly sophisticated solution like Virtualbox, or VMWare, but it may fits your needs if your requirements are not so complicated.

Installation: `sudo apt install gnome-boxes`

For details: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes

Another alternative is *Virtual Machine Manager* app, that is a desktop user interface for managing virtual machines through libvirt (that primarily targets KVM VMs, but it is able to open the Gnome Boxes VM as well).
Virtual Manager allows you to define the hardware properties of the VM through a graphical interface: the result of these settings is a description of the hardware in an XML format.

Installation: `sudo apt install virt-manager`

For details: https://virt-manager.org/